# Critical points of a graph: reach all nodes in minimum number of points and weight

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

This is a problem for a data structures and algorithms course, so I'm not looking for a specific or complete answer, but would appreciate tips to help see if I'm on the right track (or ones that can point me on the right track)

Given an undirected graph of locations, where the nodes are the locations and the roads are the edges (weighted by how much time it takes to traverse a certain road), find the minimum number of points* that can reach all nodes in a maximum weight of 5.
*Points are any points on the graph. They can be on edges or nodes. I'll call them critical points from now on.

So for example, if we have this graph:

Node1->node3(weight 1)->node2(weight 7)

node2->node1(weight 7)->node4(w 1)->node7(w 8)

Node3->node1(1)->node4(2)->node5(2)->node6(2)

Node4->node2(1)->node3(2)->node5(2)

Node5->node3(2)->node4(2)->node7(3)

Node6->node3(2)->node7(5)

Node7->node6(5)->node5(3)->node2(8)

Then the critical points would be: one on the edge between node 1 and 2, at a weight of 2 from node 1 and a weight of 5 from node 2 (note their sum must still equal 7, the original weight from node 1 to 2), and the second on node 7 itself. 
The first critical point can reach nodes 1 to 6 in max weight of 5. Only node 7 is left unreachable in weight 5 from this point, so the second critical point is on node 7 itself. Thus the whole graph is reachable from these 2 critical points in weight 5 (or less).

My idea: keep a Boolean "done" for each nose, signaling that it can or can't be reached from one of the critical points already found.
Start from some node. Use BFS and traverse the graph. On nodes that are not done, do the following:

Check the node's adjacency list. Ignore edges weighted larger than 10, since you cannot place a critical point that reaches the node you're on as well as the nodes these edges lead to. Ignore edges leading to "done" nodes. If no edges are left, add a critical point of same location as current node to the list of critical points. Else, check the largest weight edge remaining, and create a critical point on this edge: 2 options for the critical point. Either weight from curr_node to critical_point=5, and from critical_node to adjacent_node (the node the edge leads to) is edgeWeight-5, OR: weight from crtical_point to adjacent_node is 5, and from curr_node to critical_point is edgeWeight-5. Try both and check which critical point can reach more nodes in weight 5. Use the one with more reachable nodes and mark these nodes as done.

The problem here is proof of validity. There are more than just 2 options for each critical point (when using the largest weight edge) and I'm just considering 2. But on the other hand, if I consider more we go into complexity problems, and the algorithm is already not too optimized. Additionally, we may need to place more than one critical point on the edges surrounding a node. This algorithm only puts one or none and moves on, because I assumed that placing more than one might place much more points than needed.

So basically, I'm not too sure of where to go from here. Any help would be really really appreciated.

Comment: When you say "can reach all edges", do you mean every point on every edge must be within 5 of a critical point?  Or is it just every *node* (i.e. endpoint of an edge) that must be within 5 of a critical point?  E.g. if the graph is just a single edge of length 20, then 3 critical points are required if the former, but only 2 if the latter.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant every node not every edge. So just 2 in you example.

Comment: Can we assume that all edge weights are integer? If so then there must be a minimum-point solution with all critical points appearing at integer distances along an edge, and this will allow simpler algorithms because the set of possible critical point locations is then finite, so we can enumerate all possibilities easily (although this will lead to solution times that are a function of the total weight of the graph).

Comment: Another thought: given an edge, it's not sufficient to try the two critical point placements on that edge that you're considering. Consider the following graph, with edge lengths equal to the number of hyphens: `a--b------c--d`.  This can be solved using a single critical point *only* if it is placed exactly half-way between b and c, i.e. at a distance of 3 from each.

Comment: Here's the skeleton of a recursive solution that is guaranteed to find the optimum, assuming integer distances: 1. Pick any non-"done" node v. 2. Try adding a critical point at every integer point having distance <= 5 of v (there are many ways to speed up this step; see later). 3. For each possible placement, mark v and all other nodes within a distance of 5 as "done" ("done" leaf nodes and the edges to them can be deleted completely), then recurse to process the resulting graph; stop when all nodes are done.

Comment: One good way to speed this up is to look for partial solutions that *dominate* other partial solutions -- that is, partial solutions that must be at least as good some other set of partial solution(s), meaning that the latter can then be ignored. In this case, in looking at possible placements for a critical point w.r.t. some node v: if v is a leaf and the edge to it has length >= 5, there cannot be any advantage to placing the c.p. closer to v than 5 units away. Also when searching for possible placements, there will be a set of "maximally far" edges that the c.p. can be placed on...

Comment: ... while still being within 5 of v. In each case, if the furthest placement along the edge (i.e. the placement that puts the c.p. at distance exactly 5 from v) is not within 5 of the other end of the edge, then it can only be advantageous to bring the c.p. back to the very start of this edge (since this could potentially make it closer to other nodes).

Comment: True. The last post you wrote I've already addressed though, haven't I? If an edge is greater than 10, simply ignore it, as you cannot reach it and v at the same time.

Comment: My issue is where to place the critical points so as to have a minimum number of them. Aside from leaf nodes, in which it is always best to place the c.p at distance 5 from it, I didn't quite understand your recursive solution. In particular, I didn't exactly get step 3. What exactly is meant by "done" leaf nodes and edges to them can be deleted completely?

Comment: However, it might be a good way to place c.p's at all integer lengths from v, and seeing how we can get the largest number of done nodes with the smallest number of c.p's. But isn't that terrible time complexity? All possible combinations of c.p's at integer lengths, especially if we try placing more than 1 c.p (in that case you would have a huge number of possible combinations if the edge weights are large).

Answer (score 2):

*The following comes from the top of my head, you are welcome to find holes in the reasoning.*

It looks like you have the set cover problem at hand. I.e. given an instance of the set cover problem, one can build an instance of your problem, such that solving the latter would also solve the former. Of course the set cover problem is NP-complete.

Here's the reduction. Given a universal set U and some set S of its subsets that covers all of U, build a *minimal* subset of S that still covers all of U.

We build a graph G as follows. Each element u of U is a red vertex. Each element s of S is a blue vertex. If u \in s, we connect corresponding vertices with an edge of length 5. If two elements s_i and s_j of S intersect, we connect corresponding vertices with an edge of length 5. There are no other edges.

Suppose we have determined a set Q of critical points in G. If there's any non-blue point in Q, remove it and replace with a nearest blue vertex (any of them if there's more than one). *The set of reachable vertices does not become any smaller.* So for any minimal critical set we can build a blue-only minimal critical set, and blue-only critical sets are precisely set covers of U.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't quite understand a few things.
What qualifies a vertex as red or blue? I understand what the sets U and S are in the set cover problem, but not how they apply here exactly.
Also, what is meant by two elements intersecting?

If any of these question seem trivial to you, please bear with me. I wouldn't pretend to be a programming expert.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Red and blue are just arbitrary labels. There are two kinds of vertices: one vertex for each element of U (I call them red) and one vertex for each set in S (I call them blue). Given a set-cover problem, we transform it into a graph by creating red and blue vertices, and adding edges as described. If you can find a critical set of this graph, you can transform it into a solution of the set cover problem. If you can find a critical set of *any* graph, you can solve *any* instance of the set cover problem. Set cover problem is hard, so your problem must be hard too.